# Read from text file and store to collection

Tags: java, text, arraylist

I am thinking a way to store a bunch of data read from text file to a collection which is arraylist. After i read the file i have to idea how to store it. For example, data from text file:
Problem Solving with C++:Walter Savitch:9780132773348:QA760-073:NON FICTION:2 
Here is part my code:

**Get from text file:**

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
                    "Text and Data Files", "txt", "dat");
            chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
            int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(MainMenu.this);
            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                String filename = chooser.getSelectedFile()
                        .getAbsolutePath();
                readBooks(filename);
            }
        }


public void readBooks(String filename) {
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        int i = 0;
        String line;
        line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null && !line.equals("")) {
            i++;
            processBook(line);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
        System.out.println("" + i + " books read");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void processBook(String line) {
    int id = nextBookID;
    nextBookID++;

    String[] parts = line.split(":");
    String title = parts[0];
    String author = parts[1];
    String bookISBN = parts[2];
    String callNumber = parts[3];
    String type = parts[4];
    String noOfCopy = parts[5];     

    System.out.println("Creating book " + id);

    // TODO: add create book and add to collection(s)



}
```

Comment: Collection of what?? strings??

Comment: Probably i would like to set to an array list

Answer (score 2):

You should start with creating a book class:

```
public class Book() {
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private String bookISBN;
    private String callNumber;
    private String type;
    private String noOfCopy;

    public Book(String title,
        String author,
        String bookISBN,
        String callNumber,
        String type,
        String noOfCopy) {

        this.author = author;
        this.bookISBN = bookISBN;
        this.callNumber = callNumber;
        this.type = type;
        this.noOfCopy = noOfCopy;
    }
}
```

You have a class for your books now which you can store in an array list of books. In your readBooks method you should create this array list:

```
ArrayList<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now you use this list inside your processBook method. You create your Book object with the constructor I defined erlier:

```
Book book = new Book(title, author, bookISBN, callNumber, type, noOfCopy);
```

You can add this Book to your arrayList now:

```
bookList.add(book);
```

This will store your books in a collection.

Comment: Can i declare the arraylist as global variable and able to access by other method?

Comment: You can either declare it as a global veriable and access it in the other methods yes. This is another possibility.

Comment: Alright, i solve it, thx. And comparing to tree set with arraylist, which one is the recommended way to store a collection of data?

Comment: In contrast to sets lists are ordered. If you need your Books ordered you should use the ArrayList. Else it does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a class. For example:

```
public class Book{
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private String ISBN;
    private String callNumber;
    private String type;
    private String noOfCopy;

    public Book(int id, String title, String author, String ISBN, String callNumber, String type, String noOfCopy) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.ISBN = ISBN;
        this.callNumber = callNumber;
        this.type = type;
        this.noOfCopy = noOfCopy;
    }
    <Getter and Setter>
}
```

and add a new Bookinstance to an Arraylist.

```
List<Book> books= new ArrayList<Book>();
books.add(new Book(id, parts[0], parts[1], parts[2], parts[3], parts[4], parts[5]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach will be to create a `Book` class, like the following:

```
public class Book {

    private String title;
    private String author;
    private String bookISBN;
    private String callNumber;
    private String type;
    private long noOfCopy;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getBookISBN() {
        return bookISBN;
    }

    public void setBookISBN(String bookISBN) {
        this.bookISBN = bookISBN;
    }

    public String getCallNumber() {
        return callNumber;
    }

    public void setCallNumber(String callNumber) {
        this.callNumber = callNumber;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public long getNoOfCopy() {
        return noOfCopy;
    }

    public void setNoOfCopy(long noOfCopy) {
        this.noOfCopy = noOfCopy;
    }
}
```

Then just create new objects at the `processBook`:

```
Book tempBook = new Book();
tempBook.setTitle(title);
...
```

And add them to the `List`, for example:

```
List<Book> myList = new ArrayList<>();
...
myList.add(tempBook);
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done without layering code with class, you just have to use Container object (Like Vector of strings) passed as second argument to readBooks function and other functions..

But using class is better option, its more modular, maintainable and readable